# Is it possible to use named colors in Zsh beyond ANSI names?

Tags: shell, zsh, colors

I know there are ways to use ANSI color names in Zsh (such as red), but Zsh supports 256 colors by number. I'm curious if there's any way to refer to the non-ANSI colors by a name? (Without just sticking them in a variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 16 colors have been standard for a long time (and have mostly standard hues). 256 colors are a more recent extension defined by xterm and compatible terminals. The xterm documentation has this to say about colors 16–255:

> These  specify  the  colors  for  the 256-color extension.  The default resource values are for colors 16 through 231 to make a 6x6x6  color  cube,  and  colors  232  through  255  to  make a grayscale ramp.

The colors can be changed from within the terminal; see the [`ctlseqs`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) file. For example `print '\e]4;42;taupe\a'` changes color 42 to be taupe (the color names are available in `/etc/X11/rgb.txt` or some other distribution-dependent location).

If you're content to assume that the colors above 16 have their default values, you could extend the `$color` array with names from `rgb.txt`. You'll need to do a bit of arithmetic to find the closest approximation of 8-bit colors in lg(6)-bit colors.

Comment: this sounds like a PITA, you'd think someone would just do it so it doesn't have to be done on an individual system level.