# 256 colour prompt in Zsh

Tags: zsh, colors

How can I set my prompt to be colourized in 256 colours?  I am looking for an equivalent to the bash prompt:

```
  local DEFAULT="\[\033[0;39m\]"
  local ROOK="\[\033[38;5;24m\]"
  PS1="${ROOK}\$${DEFAULT} "
```

Comment: Shame on anyone who stared but not upvoted!

Comment: `export PS1='%{[38;5;24m%};%{[0m%} '` is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to use named colors in Zsh beyond ANSI names?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/is-it-possible-to-use-named-colors-in-zsh-beyond-ansi-names)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, ensure that your terminal supports 256 colors, which I suppose you already have. Second, use a `PS1` variable with the correct code, for example:

```
export PS1='%{^[[01;38;05;214;48;05;123m%}%m%{^[[0m%} '
```

This will give you a prompt with the host name in bold, with a foreground color of 214 and a background color of 123.

Note that the `^[` is "entered" by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. See this excellent article "[That 256 Color Thing](https://web.archive.org/web/20120905043337/http://lucentbeing.com/blog/that-256-color-thing)" for the whole list of attributes.

Comment: Yes, I am using urxvt 256 colour enable terminal.

Comment: How can I verify if my terminal supports 256 colors? For example, does gnome-terminal (Ubuntu) support 256 colors?

Comment: Use [this script](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/data/256colors2.pl) (full article http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/). `gnome-terminal` does support 256 colors.

Comment: The host of the link is broken (502 bad gateway).

Comment: @Pikrass I have 404 not found.

Comment: All the links seem to be broken, you can download the testing script from here: [256colors2.pl](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/xterm/precise/view/head:/vttests/256colors2.pl)

Comment: Not sure how I missed this earlier, but I updated the link in the answer with an archive.org one.

Answer (score 17):

```
export PS1='%F{214}%K{123}%m%k%f'
```

From `man zshmisc`:

```
   %F (%f)
          Start (stop) using a different foreground colour, if supported by the terminal.  The colour may be specified two ways: either as a numeric argument, as normal, or by a sequence in braces following the %F, for example %F{red}.  In the latter case the values allowed are as described for the fg zle_highlight attribute; see  Char‐
          acter Highlighting in zshzle(1).  This means that numeric colours are allowed in the second format also.

   %K (%k)
          Start (stop) using a different bacKground colour.  The syntax is identical to that for %F and %f.
```

Also to try it out it could be used like that:

```
$> print -P '%F{214}%K{123}%m%k%f'
```